# Will Angular Signals replace NgRx (a bit)?

Tags: angular, ngrx, state-management, angular-signals

I read a lot about Signals which will be released with Angular 16 and did already some coding with it. Pretty awesome!

I heard (and believe) it will probably replace almost all RxJs Code expect async related stuff like fetching an API.

My question: Isn’t it also a good way to handle the state management without third party tools like NgRx? What are your thoughts?

I worked myself in both mentioned technologies

Comment: I have created this new library it is based on signals and it's a very good replacement for ngrx

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsm-signal-state-management

https://medium.com/@mohammadrezaimn/rsm-signal-state-management-a-powerful-alternative-to-ngrx-fbcac40e53fa

Answer (score 4):

They are not the same thing:

- NgRx is a state management lib
- Signals are for fine-grained reactivity

NgRx will use signals though. There is a [current RFC](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/discussions/3796) on that topic.

Comment: I have created this new library it is based on signals and it's a very good replacement for ngrx

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsm-signal-state-management

https://medium.com/@mohammadrezaimn/rsm-signal-state-management-a-powerful-alternative-to-ngrx-fbcac40e53fa

Answer (score 3):

The following is an excerpt from the [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/signals):

> Signals can contain any value, from simple primitives to **complex
> data structures**.

If Signals can contain complex data structures, which also can be reactively accessed easily anywhere in the application in an immutable or mutable way, then Signals can be used as a fully fledged state management solution.

Signals has the full potential to replace NgRx in majority of the future Angular projects in my opinion.

Comment: Hard disagree. The concepts of effects, reducers and selectors are very valuable in large complex applications. Signals will only take you that far. A combination of both is best imho.

Answer (score 2):

Signals are never going to replace Ngrx, it's a supplement.

For very simple projects you can do without Ngrx and just go with Signals.
But if you are doing anything larger than a small project, you should use proper state management.

Ngrx can expose the selectors as Signals so you get the best of both worlds. It is truly amazing.
We have a production application now, done with Angular 16.1, it's a large Standalone app using Ngrx/Store and Signals. It's truly game changing experience and it's amazing what Signals and inject() enable.